# PhoneGap. Failed to start Geolocation service

Tags: cordova, android-emulator

PhoneGap version: 2.0.0. Android API level 16 (4.0.3 version). Code sample which prompts an error:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {enableHighAccuracy:true});

function onSuccess(position) {
    console.log('latitude: '+ position.coords.latitude);
    console.log('longitude: '+ position.coords.longitude);                  
}

function onError(error) {
    console.log('Appeared error : '+ error.message);                
}
```

Always getting an error in emulator `Failed to start Geolocation service`, error code `2`. Even if send GPS coordinates through *Android console* or *DDMS*

Android manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you testing this on the emulator only? The Geolocation Service always fails in my Android emulator but not on a real device.

EDIT: Please try using the following code

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(myPositionSuccess, myPositionError, {maximumAge: 300000, timeout:10000, enableHighAccuracy : true});
};
```

Comment: I have a real device with Android 2.3 version, but do not have a device with 4.x version. So I'm testing in emulator. Yes, in real device there is no such error. Just in emulator.

Comment: Please try adding that eventListener.

Comment: @JoãoPenetra I added this to my code and it got it to not return any errors! Thanks for that! But...now it doubles my JSONP request to Google Fusion Tables which also uses the location. Can you think of any reason why it would make two calls using the `enableHighAccuracy`? Without that in there, it only returns 1 set of data but throws an error first. Here's the file: https://github.com/jamez14/TrailFinder/blob/master/TrailFinder/www/js/map.js

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `enableHighAccuracy` option to `true` while you are trying to get the location.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,{enableHighAccuracy:true});
```

Moreover, to **specify the coordinates** of your position in the emulator,

**Eclipse -> Open Perspective -> DDMS -> Emulator Control -> Location Controls**

Specify the coordinates of the position and press **"Send"** .

Answer (score 0):

I have try to fix this issue for weeks. I search the net and it seems that most people is having this issue regarding phonegap whenever they are developing for android. The solution was to test my code on a device that has GPRS. Also make sure that before runnning your code your GPRS and wifi is enable. Avoid using emulator to test GPRS because there are lots of features missing and bugs.