# Geolocation in phonegap not working on emulator

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, geolocation

I am newbie to phonegap development. Please help me to getout from the following issue.
 I am developing a phonegap application where i have to read the current geolocation coordinates and according to that display the geolocation on map. While i am running my code in the Browser it is working fine, But when i am running the application on emulator or mobile nothing is showing on map, white screen is visible in place of map.

This is my code.Please help me,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">

        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #map_canvas { height: 100% width: 100%}

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA6YvhWQgns2SVExEys8V-WeVfxdQAIqVQ">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
  var lat  = 0;
  var long = 0;

  infowindow.open(map,marker);

function initGeolocation(){
  if( navigator.geolocation){
  // Call getCurrentPosition with success and failure callbacks
  //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, fail );
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,fail,{enableHighAccuracy:true},{timeout:9000});

  }
  else{var long = position.coords.longitude;
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  alert("Sorry, your browser does not support geolocation services.");
  }
  }

function success(position)
  {

  var long = position.coords.longitude;
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  console.log('Coordinates: ' +position.coords);
  console.log('TimeStamp' + position.timestamp);

    var myOptions =
    {

  center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long),
  zoom: 12,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
  map: map
  });
  }

  function fail()
  {
  console.log('error' +error.message);
  console.log('code' + error.code);
  alert("error");
  }

 </script>
    <div class="divImageHolder">
        <a href="menu.html" title="Mouseover Description"><img style="width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 0;" src="http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons/green-jelly-icons-media/003210-green-jelly-icon-media-a-media31-back.png" alt="Text Description"></a></div>
    </div>
</head>

<body onload="initGeolocation()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set geolocation in emulator?

Specify the coordinates of position in emulator.

**Eclipse -> Open Perspective -> DDMS -> Emulator Control -> Location Controls**

Specify the coordinates of the position and press **"Send"** .

referred from [Here][PhoneGap. Failed to start Geolocation service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797172/phonegap-failed-to-start-geolocation-service)

Comment: I am using Intellij IDE

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: @Tate No,I did't found any DDMS in intellij IDE

Comment: Then you have to use either Eclipse or compatible device for testing.